# Failed importing Facebook SDK in Swift 4.x

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sdk

I've tried to import **Facebook SDK for App Events** and tracking of App Installs through Facebook ADS and it's being impossible to do it.

I've done it with **CocoaPods** using:

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
```

as the Facebook official tutorial says.

After that, **Facebook Analytics** has detected me as a New unique user, so that is great .

The problem is when I try to add an APP Event like so:

```
AppEventsLogger.log("Opened App Main VC");
```

And then this **ERROR**  appears:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'AppEventsLogger'
```

Apart from this, also it's not detecting **AppEventsLogger** in the **AppDelegate** with the same error:

```
AppEventsLogger.activate(application)
```

I've imported in the **VC** and in the **AppDelegate** this modules/libraries:

```
import FacebookCore //in theory is just this one
import FBSDKCoreKit
```

So any tip or help is very welcomed!

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in your directory?

Comment: Yes I did. As I said, Facebook analytics detected it :( but when I try to add app events doesn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two Imports

```
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKCoreKit
```

In AppDelegate

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

When you want to log an event:

```
AppEvents.logEvent(AppEvents.Name.init(rawValue: "Opened App Main VC"))
```

For another type of AppEvents, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/blob/master/Samples/Catalog/Sources/ManualAppEventViewController.swift)

Comment: Yes, that works. I wanted to auto answer me as I finally discovered but here it is. The problem I've now is that Facebook ADS aren't detecting my App Events I don't know why :(

Comment: @SahilManchanda It says ```'activateApp()' is deprecated: The class method `activateApp` is deprecated. It is replaced by an instance method of the same name.```

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale currently it is not marked deprecated but deleted from library

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `AppEventsLogger` is changed to `AppEvents`. So change the name of AppEventsLogger and it will work fine. This is a new update in Facebook sdk.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too and in App Delegate I can change: AppEventsLogger.activate(application) to AppEvents.activateApp() and this in theory works great. The problem is that I don't know how to log then with this: AppEventsLogger.log("Hello World"); because it says the same error in the VC.

Comment: Frustratingly, the changelog covers this but all of the 'getting started' guides are currently showing older code like OP's example

Comment: @lgy...yeah they are unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly changed again:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppEvents.shared.activateApp()
}
```